# How can I open a dialog inside handleSubmit?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, modal-dialog

I have a handleSubmit component which looks like this: File.tsx
File.tsx

```
export default function SimpleDialog() {
const handleSubmit = (event: any) => {
  <SimpleDialog />;
}
return(
<form>
  <Button type="submit"> Save</Button>
</form>
)
}
```

I have another file called SimpleDialog.tsx

```
export default function SimpleDialog() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleClose = (value: string) => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {" "}
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} />{" "}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to open my dialog when I click Save button. I'm not able to open my dialog box. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can only render JSX by returning it from your functional component. Any callback is not a valid place for that.

And in this case, you really want `SimpleDialog` to keep the state about wether it's open or not. The Dialog is dumb and just need to display content, while some other component will manage that dialog, and tell what to do and when and what to show.

---

So in `handleSubmit` you want to set some state, then react to state in what you render.

For instance, first use some state that you can use to track if the dialog should be shown:

```
const [showingDialog, setShowingDialog] = useState(false)
```

Then in `handleSubmit`, set that state:

```
const handleSubmit = () => setShowingDialog(true)
```

Lastly, render your dialog if `showDialog` is `true`:

```
return (
  <div>
    { showDialog && <SimpleDialog /> }
    ...Other Content...
  </div>
)
```

You may want to change your dialog to accept a function as a prop that is called when the dialog should be dismissed. This would let you do the following to dismiss the dialog again.

```
<SimpleDialog onClickOk={() => setShowingDialog(false)} />
```

Comment: I tried that way but Dialog only shows up for 1 sec and then closes. I'm not able to interact with the Dialog

Comment: If that's happening, then something else is changing your state, or the page is reloading for some reason. I'm not sure how to help you debug that, but this general approach will work.

Comment: My handleSubmit looks like this:  
`const handleSubmit = (event: any) => {
      event.preventDefault();   
     runningSome GraphQl Query
      setShowingDialog(true)
  };`
Can event.preventDefault cause this behavior?

Comment: I tried console.log for value of showingDialog and it seems true after hitting save